# How can I use todonotes with beamer?

Tags: beamer, todonotes

I'm creating a presentation using beamer and I would like to denote bits that need to be done later using the `todonotes` package. But there appears to be some conflict between the two packages. I get errors of the form

```
! LaTeX Error: Float(s) lost.
```

I'm guessing this is because the slides don't have a margin in which to place the todo bubbles. What's the best way to get around this? I'm looking for something easier than manually adding the `inline` option to every use of `\todo`.

Comment: Beamer doesn't support floats, which don't make sense in a presentation. Marginpars are floats, so as long you can't stop `todonotes` to use them you wont come far.

Comment: @Martin: ok, thanks, so I guess the question boils down to finding the best way to automatically add the `inline` option to every instance of `\todo`.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can change the presets of the package so that it creates inline todonotes by default. In order to do this, just add the line `\presetkeys{todonotes}{inline}{}` after you have loaded `todonotes` (you may also need to add `xkeyval` to make the `\presetkeys` macro available):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\presetkeys{todonotes}{inline}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \todo{Notes are inline by default now.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This causes weird errors while the other solution is fine. Can't be bothered to find out the exact problem, just wanted to add this as a caveat for future googlers.

Comment: For recent versions of todonotes, just `\usepackage{todonotes} \setuptodonotes{inline}` works (at least for me).

Answer (score 8):

Now I feel silly, because almost immediately after posting the question I had an idea:

```
\usepackage{todonotes}
\let\todox\todo
\renewcommand\todo[1]{\todox[inline]{#1}}
```

This redefines `\todo` as `\todo[inline]`, at the expense of not allowing any other options to be given to `\todo`,  which works fine for me. Though I still welcome more flexible solutions if they are out there.

Comment: This should allow additional options (as long `\todo` accepts empty options, i.e. a trailing `,`): `\renewcommand\todo[2][]{\todox[inline,#1]{#2}}`

Comment: You can define your command to be `\renewcommand\todo[2][]{\todox[inline,#1]{#2}}`. That way, you can pass more options.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar @fabikw.

The only difference is that I want to create an optional name.

The code I tried was:

`\let\todox\todo`
`\renewcommand\todo[2][]{`
`\todox[inline,color={red!100!green!33},size=\footnotesize]{\textbf{Comment [#1]:}~#2}%`
`}`
In the argument 1, it shall be possible to write an optional name.

But this will not build. I had to cancel it, because it was getting nowhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Another option to inline todonotes by default, based of diabonas' answer, but this one doesn't require additional packages:

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\setuptodonotes{inline}
% can add other options here, e.g. \setuptodonotes{inline, color=red}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \todo{Notes are inline by default now.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```